# Firebase database startAt() string parameter length limit?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Was about to post this to their github repo, but seems like they prefer general questions to be asked here instead.

So is there any string length limit for parameter when using `startAt()` to get data from firebase database?

I've juts run into an issue where it seems like it's limited to only 41 symbol and I can't seem to find any docs to confirm that.

If it is indeed the limit, then is there any way to change it? (I need to be able to filter by values with up to 60 symbols)

I mean, I still can pass longer parameters, but the database returns results that are only filtered out by the first 41 characters ignoring the rest of the value.

I'm using js sdk in case it matters here.

The dataset (each value is about 100 characters long and the first 41 characters are identical in each of them but defferes at tails )

```
{
  "obj1": {"param": "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEF_0123456789ABCDEFabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEF"},
  "obj2": {"param": "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEF_123456789ABCDEFabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEF"},
  "obj3": {"param": "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEF_23456789ABCDEFabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEF"},
  "obj4": {"param": "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEF_3456789ABCDEFabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEF"},
  "obj5": {"param": "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEF_456789ABCDEFabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEF"}
}
```

Now I need to retrieve the "obj1" by value of the key "param" and I know only the first 60 characters of it (so I can't use equalTo() )

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("/some/data");

ref.orderByChild("param")
   .startAt("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEF_0123456789ABCDEFabc") <- this guy is 60 characters long
   .once("value")
   .then(function(snapshot) {
     snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
       console.log(child.key);
     });
   })
```

I'd expect only one result here, but instead the code above returns all the records from the set.

Comment: Could you edit the question to show the exact code you're using, and also the sample data you're working with that allows anyone to easily reproduce the issue?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this problem, see my "answer" below where I tried both with JavaScript and Swift. Please provide a [minimal complete repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks a lot for that - please check my updated answer - hope  it makes the issue more clear

Comment: If you order these children by the value of `param`, then `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEF_123456789ABCDEFabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEF` comes after `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEF_0123456789ABCDEFabc`. Keep in mind that Firebase does a start**At** operation, not a starts**With**.

Comment: It's a lot easier to see if you use shorter strings, say `"aa", "ab", "ac"`. Now if you `startAt("ab")` you will get `"ab"` and `"ac"`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen - thank, that makes sense. Then I guess if the value I'm looking for is there, firebase will return it as the first record + other data (which I can remove with limitTo(1)) and I just need to ensure this is the value I'm looking for - i.e to add one more check of the result - snapshot.forEach(function(child){if(child.val().param.indexOf(myLongKey) >= 0){//found it!//}}). Do I understand it correctly? Or probably using it like startAt(myLongKey).endAt(myLongKey) will do the trick as well?

Comment: I wrote another answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you're confused about the `startAt` operation, and are trying to use it to filter strings that start **with** a certain substring. That's not how `startAt` works however.

When you order the children by the value of `param`, Firebase orders all children by the value of that property. When you then start at `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEF_0123456789ABCDEFabc` it starts returning nodes from that point onwards. And in that order `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEF_123456789ABCDEFabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEF` comes after `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEF_0123456789ABCDEFabc`.

If you want the first child starting **at** a certain value, consider using `.startAt(searchTerm).limitToFirst(1)`.

If you want to get the children starting **with** a certain value, use a closed range `startAt(searchTerm).endAt(searchTerm+"\uf8ff")`. Here `\uf8ff` is the last unicode character.

Comment: thanks Frank - yeah, this is what I understood from your recent comment which helped a lot. It helps to get back on track if the values are numbers and not strings. So searching with startAt(2) in the dataset of [5, 6, 7]  will return all the values. And if I need exactly 2 then I can either limitToFirst(1) and check the value (which will give 5 != 2 - answer: "there is no 2 in the dataset") or use startAt + endAt (+ this hack with \uf8ff in case of strings which I didn't know). I guess startAt + endAt would be a little bit more efficient in this case. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I just tried reproducing this problem in a JavaScript project, and in a Swift project, but was unable to.

My data set:

```
{
  "key1" : "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789",
  "key2" : "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFZHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789",
  "key3" : "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFHHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789",
  "key4" : "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFIHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789",
  "key5" : "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFJHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
}
```

My JavaScript code:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("/51151783");

ref.orderByValue()
   .startAt("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFI")
   .once("value")
   .then(function(snapshot) {
     snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
       console.log(child.key);
     });
   })
```

My Swift code:

```
func searchForLongValue51151783() {
    let ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "51151783")
    ref.queryOrderedByValue().queryStarting(atValue: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFI").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            for child in snapshot.children {
                print((child as! DataSnapshot).key)
            }
    })
}
```

This outputs:

> key4
>
> key5
>
> key2

And the jsbin: http://jsbin.com/lupebuwihu/edit?js,console.

Comment: thanks a lot for your effort. Please check my updated question. Hope it clarifies the issue better.